# Selecting/Manipulating a modal after rendering

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

I have a Modal component. I need to get a handle on the modal after it is rendered and add an additional class to one of its div. How do I select the modal after it's been rendered to the DOM?

This is what I have. I am trying to render my Modal component with `myModal()` and add a class with `addClassToDiv()` in the next line in my return statement. However, I can't seem to add the class successfully. It still seems the div I am trying to select is still not on the DOM when I call the function.

```
export const CustomModal = (props) => {
    
    const myModal = () => {
        return (
            <Modal>
                <div className="some-div">{props.text}</div>
            </Modal>
        );
    };

    const addClassToDiv = () => {
        document.querySelector('.some-div').classList.add('additional-class');
    };

    return (
        <>
            {myModal()}
            {addClassToDiv()}
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: Your `addClassToDiv` is not how React works.  If you're using `querySelector` or the like, you need to reach for a dynamic approach instead.  The presence of some other div and its effect on the classList for your Modal element should be coordinated by a parent component (most likely).

Comment: The standard way to do this would be using react: `<div className="some-div additional-class">{props.text}</div>`. Is there some reason that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Thanks very much. I need to rewrite my components then. @NicholasTower I have to work around a third party library and a heavily typed environment which restricts me in some ways. Adding a class to this modal would have been an easy way out to deal with my problem without rewriting and therefore complicating things. Thanks both of you.

Comment: It is possible to write code to do what you have in mind, it's just a bad pattern to use in react, and should be avoided if there's an alternative. So i wanted to find out what your constraints are before telling you the bad way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, you should avoid doing this. It can result in brittle and unmaintainable code, so if you can do it in a way that's more standard for react, you should.

If you have no choice but to do this sort of manipulation (say, because you're using an external library that doesn't give you the interaction points you need), then you'll need to wait until after the component renders in order to make your changes. You can do this in a useEffect:

```
export const CustomModal = (props) => {
    
    const myModal = () => {
        return (
            <Modal>
                <div className="some-div">{props.text}</div>
            </Modal>
        );
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      const element = document.querySelector('.some-div');
      if (element) {
        element.classList.add('additional-class');
      }
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {myModal()}
        </>
    );
};
```

If this results in an unwanted flicker, you can switch it to useLayoutEffect instead.

Be aware that react has no idea that you're making these changes, so it will take no steps to preserve your changes. In some cases, the code in Modal may end up overwriting what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach,

```
 export const CustomModal = ({text}) => {

    useEffect(() => {
      const element = document.querySelector('.some-div');
      if (element) {
        element.classList.add('additional-class');
      }
    }, []);

    return <MyModal text={text}/>;
};
```

**Created MyModal as a separate component:-**

```
const MyModal = ({text}) => 
           <Modal>
                <div className="some-div">{text}</div>
            </Modal>;
```